# Is there a performance gain in including <script> tags as opposed to using eval?

Tags: javascript, performance, eval

I have seen a lot of suggestions about how one should add code dynamically like so [(source)](http://www.sanraul.com/2009/02/14/inserting-script-tags-at-runtime/):

```
var myScript = document.createElement("script");
myScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
myScript.innerHTML += 'alert("Hello");';
document.body.appendChild(myScript);
```

As opposed to `eval` like so

```
eval('alert("Hello");');
```

People complain about performance drops and security issues with `eval`, but I can't imagine how adding `<script>` tags would be any faster or any more secure.

---

**EDIT** people would like to know why I am evaling something as trivial as `alert("Hello")`, here is why:

I have a database of, lets say, 1,000,000,000,000 scripts =P obviously I can't load every one, instead the user can load whichever they wish. The scripts are stored serverside in arbritrary locations. Currently I request (xmlhttprequest interpreted as javascript) a script via its script name and the server will find it (somehow) and return it as text, which immediately gets executed/interpreted. I want to know if it would be better to return the script as text, then create a `<script>` tag out of it.

Also, this is NOT a duplicate of [Javascript difference between eval() and appending script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903982/javascript-difference-between-eval-and-appending-script-tags), that deals with the functional differences, here I want the performance and security differences.

Comment: I would argue that these are both just as bad. Just as trivia, one slight difference is that `eval` returns the result of the last expression evaluated.

Comment: I know "Hello" is just an example, but wouldn't you just say `alert("Hello");` directly? Can you give a more concrete example of why you'd want to dynamically insert script like that? I can understand dynamically included external script files, but what problem does the above solve (with or without `eval()`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript difference between eval() and appending script tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903982/javascript-difference-between-eval-and-appending-script-tags)

Comment: @Jergason are you implying that there is indeed a "good" way?

Comment: @nnnnnn OK I will update with more detail

Comment: @Tadeck I saw that, but it does not address my exact problem, namely is script really more efficient than `eval`

Comment: If your goal is to run an external script, then a much simpler way is to dynamically add a `<script>` element that references that script using `src=`, rather than to use `XmlHttpRequest` to retrieve the script and then set about running it.

Comment: @ruakh: I believe that this is more complex question (see [this article on On Demand JavaScript](http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/On-Demand_Javascript.php)). OP actually asks for efficiency, not ease of use (which in some cases is in favor for `eval()`, unfortunately).

Comment: @ruakh that's not the point. I just want to know if there exists any performance and/or security issues in using eval as opposed to `<script>`. If you read my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8380383/654789) below, you will see why I am not using `src=`

Comment: @puk because its telling the browsers "you know that dom tree you already have. Destroy it. And then parse this large of html back into a DOM tree. What do you mean the difference between dom trees is marginal? What do you mean you waste a shit ton of effort reparsing things you already have? What do you mean I'm taking the piss. Oh DOM why you complain so much". What you really want is `.textContent = `

Comment: @Raynos does it destroy the entire DOM, or just the one being manipulated? Would this explain why `eval` is so much faster than creating a new `<script>` tag

Comment: @puk it destroys the dom tree routed at the node, i.e. recursively removes child nodes. You do realise your doing two different things. "eval" -> launch JS interpreter, interpret and run js code. "script" -> get DOM to construct and inject a script node _then_ launch JS interpreter, interpret and run js code.

Comment: @puk sidenote 2. Storing scripts in a database is a major security risk. If theres a security flaw I can run arbitary code on any of your connected clients. They wont be happy

Comment: @Raynos - why would it destroy the existing DOM tree if used (as in the question) on a new element that hasn't been appended to the document yet?

Comment: @Raynos "script" -> get DOM to construct and inject a script node then launch JS interpreter... would explain why `<script>` takes so much longer, as demonstrated in the graphs below (however, they are much easier to debug).

Comment: @Raynos The scripts aren't actually stored **in** the database, although they might have entries in the DB. In any case, why would that be a security risk?

Comment: @Raynos could you please provide your explanation as an answer as I think it very accurately addresses the question. I'd copy paste it myself, but I don't want to steal your thunder.

Comment: @nnnnnn It destroys the non existing DOM tree that is rooted at `script`

Comment: @puk the security risk is assuming those scripts you have stored on your server are never compromised. If I compromise one of your scripts and make it rederict to evil.com then it's game over.

Comment: Please take this to a chat-room.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no performance gain using `<script>` tags as opposed to using `eval`. In the two samples you gave, `eval` is much faster in all browsers I tested. Part of the difference is that with `<script>`, in addition to running the script, it's modifying the DOM, but that's not all of it. With longer scripts, the difference is not as pronounced, but `eval` is still faster:

UPDATE: I updated the demo to better match the tests head-to-head (both are now creating `script` blocks). The results still show `eval` much faster.

jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-8380204-eval-vs-script

[image]

Thus, the reasons not to use `eval` are security-related only. From the accepted answer on [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/918414):

> 1. Improper use of eval opens up your code for injection attacks
> 2. Debugging can be more challenging (no line numbers, etc.)

There is a third one that talks about speed, but it is refuted in the comments of that answer. If you can't guarantee the source of the scripts you plan to `eval`, it should be avoided.

As an aside: Based on your usage pattern at the end of your question, you might want to check out [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) for dynamically loading scripts.

Comment: I think that example is misleading, `eval` is faster because it is one simple line whereas the other is using 4 complex lines. If you execute more complex instructions, the difference becomes marginal [example](http://jsperf.com/script-v-eval).

Comment: Note, I am not saying that your data is wrong, just inconclusive.

Comment: I only used your samples from your question. But in your tests, `eval` is more than three times faster with sub-1000ms iteration times (meaning the differences are real-world relevant). Also, 90 percent of your question seems to ask if there is a performance difference between the two. There clearly is, but it's the opposite of your original hypothesis.

Comment: To answer the title of your question directly, as demonstrated in both your and my samples, there is no performance gain using `<script>` tags as opposed to using `eval`.

Comment: I believe Raynos provided a reason for why `script` is slower than `eval`. It carries out the additional step of getting the " DOM to construct and inject a script node".

Comment: Your data is biased try this [performance test](http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-8380204-eval-vs-script/2)

Comment: @Raynos I haven't looked at how that's different than mine, but it's still showing `eval()` as faster, right? I see I used `innerHTML`, though, so your eyes probably caught on fire.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff eval is still faster but it's no longer miles faster. I normalized the differences further so the test is less bias.

Comment: @Raynos How does adding it to a container help? I didn't understand that part. And what does the hybrid show? Overall it still shows the OP's premise about script being faster is false.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff hybrid shows where the overhead is. Adding it to a container helps because it can be emptied in a teardown to normalize the test further. I need more browser data points to make a conclusion

Comment: @Raynos I added Opera and the IEs.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff you can see `eval` is better, but you can also see the difference is smaller compared to your benchmark (Hence the test is less biased, or at least I think so)

Comment: @Raynos Agreed. But in the OP's question he specifically asks for dynamically created `<script>` vs `eval()`. I used his same lines of code in mine. I had forgotten that until I just now looked.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably one of those debates that changes based upon the browser, and the programmer's own opinion. I wouldn't imagine any significant performance difference between the two approaches unless you're doing this kind of thing many many times (and even then, that'd probably be indicative if a design problem).

Just a side note; code passed to `eval()` can be particularly difficult to debug, and can't be cached in the same way that asynchronous loading of JavaScript can:

```
(function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.async = true; // HTML5
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://example.com/application.js';
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    // can be added to the body element as well, which may be better.
})();
```

Note that this is different to your code, in that, this loads a script from the server, instead of writing the Javascript directly into the element. Honestly, I can't imagine why you'd want to do that when you can just load a file remotely instead.

Comment: They are both the same (loading from the server as opposed to writing directly into element). However, to load, I would have to query from the server where the file is, then load it from the server, which is twice as slow as querying from the server and having it returned in one go. Note, however, this has nothing to do with `<script>` v `eval`

Answer (score 2):

You do realise your doing two different things.

"eval" -> launch JS interpreter, interpret and run js code.

"script" -> get DOM to construct and inject a script node then launch JS interpreter, interpret and run js code.

Basically the browser does the same as eval just. You simply have the overhead of creating and injecting a node into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

I think eval is better becouse if you create a new element and write it to the end of body, the browser never will release this memory while the script tag exists, and this will affect the general performance in some way.

In the case of eval, the speed to parse and execute (maybe) is equal to a parsed new script tag, and the string passed maybe will be released from memory when finished.

As for security, I think it might include malicious code in your eval, you can make the inclusion in script tag as well.

Anyway, avoid both, as @jergason says, are both just as bad.

Comment: Code is not coming from a user... I don't think security applies.  Code is only coming from the server, and is essentially the same as loading via httpd

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this conversation while trying to solve a similar problem.

A lot of the comments are questioning what the OPs motivations are, which is valid.

My use case addresses this need... I want to load JS code from a server, but it's not an http server.  The client (browser) connects via websocket and synchronizes to something like a server side DOM.

But nodes of the server DOM may want to issue JavaScript code to the user for manipulating those nodes.  That code wants to come over a websocket, but then the question is how to inject it into the browser.

These pieces of code also may have dependencies, so I'm writing a websocket plugin for require.js to satisfy them.... Some parts may be static files served over httpd, but others may be dynamically generated based on user ACLs.

So... Best way to inject into browser is still unclear from this thread.  Some argue that eval() is ok, but adding a script tag with innerText is another way.  Another idea is to b64 encode the src value of a script tag.

There was mention somewhere on the web that dynamically injected code does not benefit from certain code optimizations in v8, and suffers a significant loss of performance.   A basic "alert('hello world');" would probably not reveal that.  My understanding is that the JIT compiler for v8 and presumably others don't spend that optimization time because usually eval() is for trivial bits of code.