# What's the better practice: eval or append script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, eval

I need to execute a custom piece of JavaScript I got from some AJAX call. I could do an `eval` of the string or I could just append it in a `script`-tag to the DOM. Which method would be better?

```
var dynamicScript = 'alert(\'Hello world!\');';
```

Method 1 - **Script**:

```
var x = '<script type="text/javascript">' + dynamicScript  +'</scr' + 'ipt>';
$(document.body).append(x);
```

Method 2 - **Eval**:

```
eval(dynamicScript);
```

What method is better and why? Or is there  an ever better alternative?

Comment: PS. If you decide to use method 1, change the code to `$('<scipt>').text(dynamicScript).appendTo(document.body);` Imagine what happens when `dynamicScript` contains  `"</script>"`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I prefer `eval`, because it's generally [faster](http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-script-tag/2) than creating a script tag, and appending it (especially if you wanted to create and insert it using jQuery).

Side note (useful application of a script tag) *I also use the script-tag-insertion method: In Google Chrome's extensions, injecting script-tags is the only way to run code in the scope of a page, because the `window` object is sandboxed.*

PS. Notion of [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/). This method might be useful.

Comment: See also [Is there a performance gain in including <script> tags as opposed to using eval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380204/is-there-a-performance-gain-in-including-script-tags-as-opposed-to-using-eval).

Answer (score 3):

Add it to the DOM. Reasons (taken from http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript ):

The JavaScript will automatically be evaluated in much the same way as JavaScript linked in the static HTML is evaluated when the  tag is first encountered. You can declare a bare function or variable without adding it to the window.

You can load JavaScript from external domains.

The URL points to a specific Javascript resource. With XMLHttpRequest, there's more flexibility: you can, for example, send several JavaScript snippets inside different XML nodes.

The DOM is affected in a different way. Even if the behaviour is transient, the script will be added to the DOM, whereas it would disappear after an XMLHttpRequest callback eval'd it.

Comment: That's different. It's discussing where the javascript exists at a known url. In the question here, both alternatives concern javascript generated dynamically by an ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Neither method is really that good for what you're doing. Your AJAX call should be returning data not serialized scripts. Both of your methods open you up to script injection.

`eval` should be avioded at all costs. It's slow and dangerous, [eval is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If the ajax call is returning html with script tags, you can use $.load() to import the script.

http://api.jquery.com/load/