# Loading script content from data URL

Tags: javascript

I'm just testing whether it is possible to load a script via data url. To my surprise in my actual Chromium it works.

I load the following document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'data:text/javascript,alert("hello!");';
            head.appendChild(script);
            head.removeChild(script);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

... and a box telling "hello!" pops up.

Isn't this as bad as `eval()`? This makes it possible to compile arbitrary contents (containing any POSTed content or GET parameters) and to "inject" it into the running code!

Can someone please tell me whether this is an intended behaviour common to actual browsers?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129666/whats-the-better-practice-eval-or-append-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really differ from `eval()`, because it has almost the same behavior. However, in some cases [eval() is not evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).