# Jquery: Execute jquery script in a (string)variable from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know its a bit confusing question. Please let me elaborate.

I need to execute a `jquery script` written in a text file that I am getting from a `ajax` request.

e.g. I am getting the following code from ajax request

```
($($("#jstreeblock").children().children().children()[0]).children('li').attr('id'))
```

I need to execute and store the result of above script in a variable.

for another and simple example.
I have gotten

```
'a'+'b'
```

if i execute the above script the result will be `ab` but if I am running it with `eval` I am getting error

**script**

```
<script>
var a = "'a'+'b'"
console.log(a); // printing 'a'+'b'
eval(a); // it should give ab but not giving any result
</script>
```

if I am running it as

```
eval(''a'+'b'')
```

is giving error, given below

**error**

> VM157982:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string(…)(anonymous
>   function) @ VM157981:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @
>   VM156978:878InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @
>   VM156978:811InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM156978:667

Please help and many thanks

Comment: Create a `<script>` tag, append ur code into it, append the whole `script` element to the body of the current document

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129666/whats-the-better-practice-eval-or-append-script

Comment: While possible, it's definitely a better idea to avoid executing scripts you receive, an hijacker might be able to execute malicious code. If possible, try just sending data and do something based on the data you receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `eval` should work in this case. But really not sure how you are calling it. You say that you are calling it as `eval(''a'+'b'')`, which should be  `eval("'a'+'b'")`. That might also be the reason.

Now, regarding `eval`, it is a dangerous idea to use it as @Sosdoc suggests. However, Just to address your case, check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfkzxgqr/1/) where I have a mocked `json` response and the `eval` works fine. I have also added [commented] your `"'a'+'b'"` case. You can check that as well. It should give you `ab` as a result.

Also find this excellent answer from user @Chocula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-inside-div-retrieved-by-ajax) to know more about this,

> JavaScript inserted as DOM text will not execute. However, you can use
>   the dynamic script pattern to accomplish your goal. The basic idea is
>   to move the script that you want to execute into an external file and
>   create a script tag when you get your Ajax response. You then set the
>   src attribute of your script tag and voila, it loads and executes the
>   external script.