# Should i insert a <script> or should i eval?

Tags: javascript, xss, eval

I have JavaScript code in a string which i obtained dynamically according to certain conditions (result of certain user actions).

Now i'm wondering whether i should simply `eval` it (will work, tested) or should i be inserting a `<script>` in the DOM with the value of the string inside it. The XSS risk part is clear to me (the script absolutely does not use anything that the user enters). Would like to know scope related issues (if any) arising due to insertion of a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Why? Why not query the server for *data*, and work with data, instead of code.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380204/is-there-a-performance-gain-in-including-script-tags-as-opposed-to-using-eval) talks about performance.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Its JS based animations based on user inputs. Can't do it on the server side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no security advantage to making a script element and inserting the javascript over `eval`ing it. Using `eval` means that it has access to any local variables, so scoping is only an issue if your `eval`d code needs access to local variables.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to avoid eval if the code you are evaluating is coming from a trusted source. If it's data on your server and contains no user generated code then eval away. Eval isn't always evil.

Comment: Yes. But what about scope?

Comment: Code that you `eval` will be contained in the current scope you're in. Variable declarations and such will be contained to the function scope just as if they were declared outside of the `eval`. `Eval` does not generate any scope of it's own.